# Finding amplitude of Fourier coefficient

Tags: summation, physics, fourier-series, mathematical-physics

I'm dealing with a confusing problem related to radiative transfer in atmospheres. In this problem, the solar flux on a planet it being modeled by:
$S(t)=S_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n\,e^{in\omega t}$, and temperature modeled by $T(t)=T_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n\,e^{in\omega t-\phi}$

My question is a math one, not a thermodynamics one. By using the relation 
$\sigma\,T^4(t)=(1-A)\,S(t)$ (I think), I'm supposed to be able to find the amplitude of the fourier coefficient $T_n$ to be 
$T_n=\frac{\frac{1}{4}(S_n/S_0)T_0}{\sqrt{1+tan^2(\phi)}}$.

Working backwards, I've reduced this to $\frac{T_n}{T_0}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{S_n}{S_0}cos(\phi)$, but I'm not sure what else I can do.

Potentially useful relation: $tan(\phi)=n\omega\tau,\ \tau=C_PP_0/4\sigma T_0^3g$.

Comment: What is $A$ and $\sigma$ in your question?

Comment: Sorry, $A$ is albedo (unitless) and $\sigma$ is the Stefan–Boltzmann constant. I'm not how they disappear from the solution.

Comment: Do you have an expression for $A$?

Comment: Not in this context, it's just a constant.

Comment: Could you provide some reference to the problem? As it is I don't know how you could get rid of $\sigma$ and $A$.

Comment: So the big equation these are part of is $\frac{C_P\,P_0}{g}\frac{dT}{dt}=(1-A)\,S(t)-\sigma\,T^4(t)$, which is about radiation transfer in atmospheres. The given equation for $T(t)$ in my question is an approximate solution to this equation.

I also don't see how to get rid of $A$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Where did you find the relation $T_n/T_0 = \frac{1}{4}\cos\theta S_n/S_0$?

Comment: That was from $T_n=\frac{\frac{1}{4}(S_n/S_0)T_0}{\sqrt{1+tan^2(\phi)}}$, which was given as the answer to get to. I just rearranged it a bit and did $1/\sqrt{1+tan^2(\phi)}=1/\sqrt{sec^2(\phi)}=1/sec(\phi)=cos(\phi)$.

Comment: Sorry. But is it possible to get the original source of the problem?

Comment: I wish I could, but this isn't from a textbook. The only other information I have for this problem is $tan(\phi)=n\omega \tau$, where $\tau=C_P\,P_0/4\sigma\,T_0^3\,g$, and $C_P$ is the specific heat at constant pressure, $P_0$ is surface pressure, and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: I hadn't considered this until I just now wrote it out, but maybe that expression for $\tau$ can make this work? It has the $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\sigma$. Also I think I might be able to neglect the factor of $(1-A)$ because I'm just trying to get a characteristic amplitude of $T_n$